# Getting the primary key columns off a table

Tags: postgresql-11

I have a **postgresql 11** database and I am trying to follow [this official post](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Retrieve_primary_key_columns) on getting the primary key column from a table. However I get an error saying that my table is not an existing column.

```
ERROR:  column "tablename" does not exist
LINE 10: ...* from pg_index WHERE indisprimary AND indrelid = "tablename"...
                                                              ^
```

The code looks like this:

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = "tablename"::regclass -- <--- This is the problem
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

I believe the issue has something t do with the `::regclass` cast as looking at the full table and replacing `"tablename"::regclass` with the indrelid number works fine, in my case it was 16490.

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = 16490 -- "tablename"::regclass <--- replace with the number
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

Any ideas on why the official example is not working and how I can fix it?

Comment: `'tablename'` instead of `"tablename"`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thank you. Turns out that table names with capital letters require `'"TableName"'::regclass` not jut `"TableName"::regclass`, that is both single and double quotation marks.

Comment: I suspect more that the reserved word table is to be blamed for that ...

Comment: @eagle275, the actual name of my table does not include the words table or name. The double quotation marks are needed to keep capital letters though. For example `'DogHouses'` would be interpreted as _doghouses_ whereas `'"DogHouses"'` is interpreted _DogHouses_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/253709/getting-the-primary-key-columns-off-a-table?noredirect=1#comment500305_253709), the `tablename` must be within single quotation marks, even if double quotation marks are used for keeping capital letters, which I needed. Using both solved the problem

**MWE**

```
SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) AS data_type
FROM   pg_index i
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid
                     AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey)
WHERE  i.indrelid = '"tablename"'::regclass -- <--- Using both single and double quotation marks
AND    i.indisprimary;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214576/how-do-i-get-the-primary-keys-of-a-table-from-postgres-via-plpgsql ...

if schema is needed please modify slightgly to

```
SELECT               
  pg_attribute.attname, 
  format_type(pg_attribute.atttypid, pg_attribute.atttypmod) 
FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute, pg_namespace 
WHERE 
  pg_class.oid = 'MY TABLE'::regclass AND 
  indrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  nspname = 'MY CLASS' AND 
  pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
  AND indisprimary
```

Comment: Already saw that but it did not change the problematic code.